# Connection between flex and java failing on server

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

Hi
I am working on a project using flex/java/blazeds. This worked fine on local host however now that i have uploaded to a tomcat server(online), after having an error with the service uri, this error has now seemingly been solved, yet I am receiving another error which is as follows:

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://mydomain.co.cc/site/messagebroker/amf'"]
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? i looked around online and found some suggestions but none of them seem to have helped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is context root of your online application? Am I right if it is not `http://mydomain.co.cc/site/` but `http://mydomain.co.cc/`?

Comment: well, site is the project's name, so i guess you are correct. thanks for the reply btw

Comment: I suppose the problem is in endpoint configuration in `services-config.xml`. What url you have there?

Comment: Originally the url returned was:
'http://mydomain.co.cc/blazeds/messagebroker/amf', the url I posted above occured when i changed the context root from "/blazeds" to "/site" as someone suggested thatchanging the context root the your project's name solves the problem

Comment: Can you please just paste the url from endpoint configuration of your `services-config.xml`? It will be more helpful to answer.

Comment: <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel"><endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
</channel-definition>

Comment: Try to remove `{context.root}` and rebuild client.

Comment: I removed it yet I am still reciving the same error, with the same link

Comment: Ok. Try to hardcode the right url in endpoint settings for a while and check the result.

Comment: Could you also post your web.xml?  What happens if you try to access http://mydomain.co.cc/site/ with your browser?

Comment: when i was using it offline the url was hardcoded to "http://localhost:8080/blazeds/messagebroker/amf", I assume that, the url on the server should be the same but substituting the locahost:8080  to my domain name. am i right?

Comment: OK. I have managed to solve it, in the remote version the url had an extra /blazeDs, so after reloading and remove the extra folder the error is not occuring. Thanks to both of you, couldnt have done it without you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the url on the server had an additional "/blazeds", once I re uploaded the file in a way to remove this the error did not occur.

Thanks once again for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://localhost/admin/amf'"]
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()
at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()
at mx.messaging::ChannelSet/faultPendingSends()
at mx.messaging::ChannelSet/channelFaultHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.messaging::Channel/connectFailed()
at mx.messaging.channels::PollingChannel/connectFailed()
at mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel/statusHandler()
```